# Swiper Slider is not working in tabs wordpress elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, swiper.js

I am trying to load the carousel (`swiper slider`) inside some tabs in Elementor WordPress. The carousel works fine before clicking on tabs, but whenever I click on tabs, the carousel shows but does not "slide".
I have seen few questions regarding this topic and tried their solutions, but no luck.
Right now, I am trying this code in (`child-theme/function.php`) which is giving me an error:

> Error -> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined"

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'swiperCarousel', 9999999999);
function swiperCarousel() {
    ?>
    <script>
var refreshSliders = function(){

        jQuery( ".swiper-container" ).each(function( index ) {
            swiperInstance = jQuery(this).data('swiper');
            swiperInstance.params.observer = true;
            swiperInstance.params.observeParents = true;
            swiperInstance.update();
        });

}

window.onload = function()
{
    console.log('Document loaded');
   
   jQuery("#aws-carousel-switcher").on("click", function(){ 
       console.log('Tab has been clicked');
            var $this = jQuery(this);
    
    refreshSliders();
    
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $this.offset().top - 220
                    }, 500); 

        
    });
}
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

The error is being generated from this line:

```
 swiperInstance.params.observer = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

this will work for you.

> ```
> jQuery(".swiper-container li").click(function(){
>     setTimeout(function(){ window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); }, 1000);
>
> })
> ```

select your respective tab selector.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We appreciate your sharing your insights with this community. Consider editing to improve the quality of your answer by highlighting important bits of your solution and explaining how/why it solves the OP's issue. You may also include a link back to documentation if you have one. SO accepts, but discourages, link-only answers. Most upvotes are accrued over time from quality answers that help future users learn something that they can then apply to their own coding issues, prevent new issues, or increase their general knowledge base. We look forward to more of your insights.